# xrdb colon missing error

Tags: x11, rxvt

I use my `~/.Xresources` file to configure `URxvt`, and after adding comments to the file, it seems to have caused `xrdb` to stop accepting the file.

I now get this:

```
xrdb: colon missing on line 3, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 5, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 7, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 9, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 11, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 13, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 14, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 16, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 18, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 20, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 22, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 24, ignoring line
xrdb: colon missing on line 26, ignoring line
```

What is odd is that those are not all comment lines. Some of them are, some of them are blank, some of them are actual configuration lines. It's also odd that it seems to cut off past a certain point, the file is 42 lines.

My `~/.Xresources` file is as

```
! === URvxt Configuration Section ===:

    ! Turn off the scrollbar.
    URxvt*scrollBar:            true

    ! Set an external border of 4 pixels.
    URxvt*externalBorder:   4

    ! Make the pointer blink.
    URxvt*pointerBlink:     true

    ! Save as many lines as zsh.
    URxvt*saveLines:            100000

    ! Set font to Terminus
    URxvt*font:             xft:Terminus:size=10

    ! === URxvt Colorscheme Section ===

        ! Set the foreground (text) to pure white.
        URxvt.foreground:       #FFFFFF

        ! Set the background to a grey-black.
        URxvt.background:       #151515

        ! Color 0 - Primary Background
        URxvt.color0:           #151515

        ! Color 1 - Primary Foreground
        URxvt.color1:           #FFFFFF

        ! Color 2 - Secondary Background
        URxvt.color2:           #1F1F1F

        ! Color 3 - Secondary Foreground
        URvxt.color3:           #787878

    ! === END URxvt Colorscheme Section

! === END URvxt Configuration Section ===
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `xrdb` is expecting comments to always start with '!' in the first column.

The [documentation](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/XWindow-User-HOWTO-8.html) is not totally clear on this: "If a line begins with ! (exclamation point), it is considered a comment, and the rest of the line is ignored"

Comment: The suggested link isn't the "documentation".  The BNF in the X manual page ***is***, and is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but for those experiencing the same thing, here's the answer:

You have white-space in front of your comment delimiter ( '!' ) in your Xresources file.
That's a big no-no and is the cause of your problems.
This will also happen in Xinit, Xdefaults & etc. files that directly interact w/ the XServer.
X-Files don't like white-space in front of a comment delimiter @ the beginning (or end) of a line.
If you copied & pasted your code into the file, you have some clean-up work to do. ;-)
White-space --> bad.

Answer (score 0):

See the ["X" manual page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xman.1.html), e.g., the section on [*resources*](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man7/X.7.html#toc13):

```
ResourceLine    =    Comment | IncludeFile | ResourceSpec | <empty line>
Comment         =    "!" {<any character except null or newline>}
IncludeFile     =    "#" WhiteSpace "include" WhiteSpace FileName WhiteSpace
FileName        =    <valid filename for operating system>
ResourceSpec    =    WhiteSpace ResourceName WhiteSpace ":" WhiteSpace Value
ResourceName    =    [Binding] {Component Binding} ComponentName
Binding         =    "." | "*"
WhiteSpace      =    {<space> | <horizontal tab>}
Component       =    "?" | ComponentName
ComponentName   =    NameChar {NameChar}
NameChar        =    "a"-"z" | "A"-"Z" | "0"-"9" | "_" | "-"
Value           =    {<any character except null or unescaped newline>}
```

The syntax for **`Comment`** doesn't include any whitespace before "!".
Since it doesn't match that, the next best is **`ResourceSpec`**, which was not OP's intention.